# How do you use DynamoDB Local with the AWS Ruby SDK?

Tags: ruby, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

Amazon's [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Tools.DynamoDBLocal.html) provides examples in Java, .NET, and PHP of how to use DynamoDB Local. How do you do the same thing with the [AWS Ruby SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/frames.html)?

My guess is that you pass in some parameters during initialization, but I can't figure out what they are.

```
dynamo_db = AWS::DynamoDB.new(
  :access_key_id => '...',
  :secret_access_key => '...')
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Are you using v1 or v2 of the SDK? You'll need to find that out; from the short snippet above, it looks like v2. I've included both answers, just in case.

v1 answer:

```
AWS.config(use_ssl: false, dynamo_db: { api_verison: '2012-08-10', endpoint: 'localhost', port: '8080' })
dynamo_db = AWS::DynamoDB::Client.new
```

v2 answer:

```
require 'aws-sdk-core'
dynamo_db = Aws::DynamoDB::Client.new(endpoint: 'http://localhost:8080')
```

Change the port number as needed of course.

Comment: I'm not sure how this answer can be right: Aws::DynamoDB.new gives `undefined method 'new' for Aws::DynamoDB:Module`.

Comment: aws-sdk-core-2.0.21. What works for me is `Aws::DynamoDB::Client.new(...)`.

Comment: yes, somehow, I missed the ::Client in my v2 answer, my v1 answer should still have been correct. Updated the answer. Sorry.

Comment: No, thank you! The endpoint parameter is the secret sauce. :-)

Comment: You may need to specify the region:
`dynamo_db = Aws::DynamoDB::Client.new(region: 'us-west-2', endpoint: 'http://localhost:8080')`
if Rails complains about the lack of it

Answer (score 6):

Now `aws-sdk` version `2.7` throws an error as **Aws::Errors::MissingCredentialsError: unable to sign request without credentials set** when keys are absent. So below code works for me

```
dynamo_db = Aws::DynamoDB::Client.new(
  region: "your-region",
  access_key_id: "anykey-or-xxx",
  secret_access_key: "anykey-or-xxx",
  endpoint: "http://localhost:8080"
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I've written a simple gist that shows how to start, create, update and query a local dynamodb instance.

https://gist.github.com/SundeepK/4ffff773f92e3a430481

Heres a run down of some simple code:

Below is a simple command to run dynamoDb in memory

```
#Assuming you have downloading dynamoDBLocal and extracted into a dir called dynamodbLocal
java -Djava.library.path=./dynamodbLocal/DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar ./dynamodbLocal/DynamoDBLocal.jar -inMemory -port 9010
```

Below is a simple ruby script

```
require 'aws-sdk-core'

dynamo_db = Aws::DynamoDB::Client.new(region: "eu-west-1", endpoint: 'http://localhost:9010')
    dynamo_db.create_table({
    table_name: 'TestDB',
    attribute_definitions: [{
        attribute_name: 'SomeKey',
        attribute_type: 'S'
    },
    {
        attribute_name: 'epochMillis',
        attribute_type: 'N'
    }
    ],
    key_schema: [{
        attribute_name: 'SomeKey',
        key_type: 'HASH'
    },
    {
        attribute_name: 'epochMillis',
        key_type: 'RANGE'
    }
    ],
    provisioned_throughput: {
        read_capacity_units: 5,
        write_capacity_units: 5
    }
    })
dynamo_db.put_item( table_name: "TestDB",
    item: { 
    "SomeKey" => "somevalue1", 
    "epochMillis" => 1
})
puts dynamo_db.get_item({
    table_name: "TestDB",
    key: { 
    "SomeKey" => "somevalue",
    "epochMillis" => 1
}}).item
```

The above will create a table with a range key and also add/query for the same data that was added. Not you must already have version 2 of the aws gem installed.